# Display JavaScript variable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I programmed a Tic-Tac-Toe game with HTML and JavaScript and wanted to display the scores (wins, ties, and losses).  I set three variables in the script as shown below (win, loss, and tie) however I do not know how to display those variables constantly.

My code is:
 on [this website](http://632617.wix.com/tictactoegame)

---

My code is below and I want to display the variables, win loss and tie that update constantly:
        
        
        Tic-Tac-Toe
        Will Machines Conquer Mankind?

```
                    if (document.all||document.getElementById){
                document.write('<style>.tictac{')
                document.write('width:50px;height:50px;')
                document.write('}</style>')
                }

                var sqr1
                var sqr2
                var sqr3
                var sqr4
                var sqr5
                var sqr6
                var sqr7
                var sqr8
                var sqr9
                var sqr1T = 0;
                var sqr2T = 0;
                var sqr3T = 0;
                var sqr4T = 0;
                var sqr5T = 0;
                var sqr6T = 0;
                var sqr7T = 0;
                var sqr8T = 0;
                var sqr9T = 0;
                var moveCount = 0;
                var turn = 0;
                var mode = 1;
                var win = 0;
                var lose = 0;
                var draw = 0;

                function help() {
                alert("Welcome to Daniel Schwartz's Will Machines Conquer Mankind: Tic-Tac-Toe!  You " + name + " play as the X's and Daniel Schwartz's Artifical Intelligence plays as the O's.  You " + name + " select the square you want to put your X into by clicking it.  A rule is that a X or an O cannot occupy a square that is already occupied by another X or O. The first player to get three squares filled with the user's letter (X's or O's) in a row wins.  Good Luck and enjoy Daniel Schwartz's Will Machines Conquer Mankind: Tic-Tac-Toe!!")
                }

                function vari()
                {
                sqr1 = document.tic.sqr1.value
                sqr2 = document.tic.sqr2.value
                sqr3 = document.tic.sqr3.value
                sqr4 = document.tic.sqr4.value
                sqr5 = document.tic.sqr5.value
                sqr6 = document.tic.sqr6.value
                sqr7 = document.tic.sqr7.value
                sqr8 = document.tic.sqr8.value
                sqr9 = document.tic.sqr9.value
                }
                function check()
                {
                  if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr3 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  } 
                  else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr6 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  } 
                  else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr8 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr7 == " X ")
                  {
                    win = win + 1;                    
                    alert(name + " Wins!   " + name + " beat the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    winCheck()
                    check2()
                    drawCheck()  
                  } 
                }

                function check2()
                {
                  vari()
                  drawCheck()
                  if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " O " && sqr3 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  } 
                  else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr6 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  } 
                  else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr7 == " O ")
                  {
                    lose = lose + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " Loses!   " + name + " lost to the artificial intelligence!")
                    reset()
                  }
                }

                function drawCheck()
                {
                  vari()
                  moveCount = sqr1T + sqr2T + sqr3T + sqr4T + sqr5T + sqr6T + sqr7T + sqr8T + sqr9T 
                  if(moveCount == 9)
                  {
                    draw = draw + 1;                      
                    alert(name + " and the computer have come to a draw!")
                    reset()
                  }
                }

                function winCheck()
                {
                  check2()
                  if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr3 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr3 == " O " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
                    sqr2T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
                    sqr4T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr8 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
                    sqr8T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
                    sqr4T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
                    sqr2T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr8 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
                    sqr8T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr6 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr6 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr9 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " O " && sqr7 == " O " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    computer()
                  }
                  check2()
                }
                function computer()
                {
                  check2()
                  if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn ==1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr6 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }           
                  else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
                    sqr2T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
                    sqr4T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr8 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
                    sqr8T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr4 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr4T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
                    sqr4T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr4 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr2T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
                    sqr2T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr2 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr8T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
                    sqr8T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr6 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr6 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr1T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    sqr1T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr7T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    sqr7T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr7 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr9 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr5 == " O " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;
                  }
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr2 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }                       
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr3 == " X " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }         
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr7 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }
                  else if(sqr8 == " X " && sqr5T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    sqr5T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }                                                   
                  else if(sqr3 == " X " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr9T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    sqr9T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }                                             
                  else if(sqr1 == " X " && sqr5 == " O " && sqr8 == " X " && sqr6T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    sqr6T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }     
                  else if(sqr1 == " O " && sqr5 == " X " && sqr9 == " X " && sqr3T == 0 && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    sqr3T = 1;
                    turn = 0;                       
                  }     
                  else
                  {
                    ArtificialIntelligence()
                  }
                  check2()
                }

                function ArtificialIntelligence()
                {
                  vari()
                  if(document.tic.sqr1.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr1.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr1T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr2.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr2.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr2T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr3.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr3.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr3T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr4.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr4.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr4T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr5.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr5.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr5T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr6.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr6.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr6T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr7.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr7.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr7T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr8.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr8.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr8T = 1
                  }
                  else if(document.tic.sqr9.value == "     " && turn == 1)
                  {
                    document.tic.sqr9.value = " O "
                    turn = 0
                    sqr9T = 1
                  }
                  check2()
                }

                function reset()
                {
                  document.tic.sqr1.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr2.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr3.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr4.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr5.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr6.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr7.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr8.value = "     "
                  document.tic.sqr9.value = "     "
                  sqr1T = 0
                  sqr2T = 0
                  sqr3T = 0
                  sqr4T = 0
                  sqr5T = 0
                  sqr6T = 0
                  sqr7T = 0
                  sqr8T = 0
                  sqr9T = 0
                  vari()
                  turn = 0
                  moveCount = 0
                }

                function resetter()
                {
                  reset()
                }
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="box">
        <h1>Created By: Daniel Schwartz</h1>
        <font size="10" color="orange">Cherokee High School</font>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you have already attempted? Thanks

Comment: Look at binding systems like Knockout.js.

Comment: [Off] You should apply an error margin to cpu inteligence because its impossible to win seeing that it scans for all user possibilities to score and blocks it. Or even a way to cpu to start and give human player a better chance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementbyId("anyid").innerHTML = score;`
Just equate your score variable to the innerHTML of "anydiv".
For Reference [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated fiddle from your original. As peeyushsrj mentioned, you will need to update your element(s) with the scores.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Mxht/2/

I added the following HTML

```
    <br />
    Wins : <span id="wins">0</span>
    Ties : <span id="ties">0</span>
    Loses: <span id="losses">0</span>
    <br />
```

The JavaScript is very straight forward. Within your `reset` function, I check your variables and assign that value to the element's innerHTML.

```
    // Update win/loss/tie values
    //wins is the div id, win is the variable
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = win;

    //ties is the div id, draw is the variable
    document.getElementById('ties').innerHTML = draw;

    //losses is the div id, lose is the variable
    document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = lose;
```

Hope this helps! :)